ent how to update an entity based on queried entity
I'm new to ent orm, and I am trying to update an entity like this way:
user, _ := client.User.Query().Where(entuser.UserId(userId)).First()

user.Nickname = "new name"

user.Update().Save()

But It seems not work.
I know that I can update it with SetXXX(), But I found that the ent has an oldValue field on UserMutation, So I suggest that is there someway to modify the original entity and then update it directly. like some orm in PHP

Basically ent does not track changes on struct fields. So this will never work. I think you should use SetXXX() and Update()  because that is the idiomatic way provided by ent.

@Mahesh It seems to be true, Maybe I need to use external template
